# Rails - Blank Email after extending existing Mailer with a new layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I am fairly new to ActionMailer and am working on adding a mailer which behaves just like an existing mailer, but specifies a different layout. The setup looks something like this:

```
class MailerNew < MailerOld
  layout "emails/layout_new"

  def send(arg1, arg2)
      method_of_mailer_old(arg1, arg2)
  end
end
```

As you can see, I want MailerNew to call a method of MailerOld, but with the new layout active.

When I try this, my email has an empty body. Does anybody know what is causing this?

Comment: What’s in your new layout?

Comment: For debugging, my new layout is exactly the same as the old one, but I still get a blank email

Comment: Is your method actually called `send`? That already has a meaning in Ruby. Not sure if that would really matter, but maybe…?

Comment: no it's not, sorry, I should have been clearer with my pseudocode perhaps :)

Comment: I think in your new layout you miss <%= yield %> to write. Yield will render the content as it invoked.

Comment: Nope, it definitely is an issue with the inheritance. My new layout works as expected when I extend ActionMailer::Base. There is only an issue when extending OldMailer